# Can I make a macro to execute debug or release code?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

For example if I had this code:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
    mPluginsCfg = "plugins_d.cfg";
#else
    mPluginsCfg = "plugins.cfg";
#endif
```

Can I define a macro that looks like

```
#define DEBUG_RELEASE(debug_code, release_code)
```

and then use it like this;

```
DEBUG_RELEASE(mPluginsCfg = "plugins_d.cfg";,mPluginsCfg = "plugins.cfg";)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure that it works, and I'm *almost* sure that it is *defined* to work.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_RELEASE(d,r) d
#else
#define DEBUG_RELEASE(d,r) r
#endif
```

I'm unsure whether I've seen anything uglier in the wonderful world of preprocessor macros.

Comment: If you haven't seen anything uglier, you haven't seen the more insane things people have made out of macros. But yeah, at least when used like OP uses it, it's rather ugly.

Comment: Oh, it's that simple? For some reason, I was trying to do that with having the #ifdef inside the #define. I don't see why it is ugly tho. I mean it beat having to write the full thing out every time no?

Comment: @delnan I agree. If you wonder for enough time in the C world, you will see more uglier stuff. It's pretty powerful though; can do many things that only C++ has.

Comment: @delnan I've seen way more convoluted things, of course, and what's ugly here is the supposed usage of `DR(code(but,with,no,outer,commas);,other_code();)`. Nothing ugly about `DR(expression,expression)`.

Comment: @BringMeAnother: There are many better approaches. For your particular example, just use an `#ifdef` to control the filename: `#ifdef _DEBUG\n const char* file = "plugins_d.cfg";\n #else ...`. The **huge** difference is that this changes data, not the code that gets executed. Executing different code paths in debug/release is the best recipe for long hours debugging issues that just happen in release and cannot be reproduced in debug mode. An even better approach is not to define that as a constant at all, but take the configuration file as an argument to your program.

Comment: @BringMeAnother: Note that debug/release is a property of the generated binary, and the configuration file used to drive the behavior is a property of a particular run of the program. Binding one to the other means that if you want to debug some behavior in production in a debug build you will need to create a `plugins_d.cfg` that has the exact same contents as the `plugins.cfg` that was in production.